# How assign new simple_oauth scopes?

Tags: javascript, 9, authentication-authorization

I've a problem with  [simple_oauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) module and scopes, on a D 9.3.x site.

I'm using it to authenticate user in a decoupled front-end in Next.js.

The case is:

- A (new) user log-in without roles expect *authenticated*
- After  he compiles a form in the front end, he is assigned a new role, e.g. *role 1*

However I can't refresh the token with a scope with the now role.
Looking at the the debug token end-point, he is still just *authenticated*.

From my tests:

- if a user log-in while already having a *role 1*: if the authentication token is generated with the *role 1* in the scope, this works. Both for access and refresh tokens.
- The same does not for roles assigned after the login

Is there a solution to this problem?